# ipython notebook failed to restart kernel OsX

Tags: macos, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Notebook fails to start after updating ipython to `3.2.1` from `2.*`

Terminal log:

```
MacBook-Pro-kataev:dropbox kataev$ ipython notebook --debug
[D 15:42:17.855 NotebookApp] Config changed:
[D 15:42:17.856 NotebookApp] {'NotebookApp': {'log_level': 10}}
[D 15:42:17.856 NotebookApp] IPYTHONDIR set to: /Users/kataev/.ipython
[D 15:42:17.857 NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/Users/kataev/.ipython/profile_default'
[D 15:42:17.857 NotebookApp] Searching path [u'/Users/kataev/Dropbox', u'/Users/kataev/.ipython/profile_default', '/usr/local/etc/ipython', '/etc/ipython'] for config files
[D 15:42:17.857 NotebookApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
[D 15:42:17.858 NotebookApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_notebook_config.py
[D 15:42:17.861 NotebookApp] searching for local mathjax in [u'/Users/kataev/.ipython/nbextensions', '/Users/kataev/anaconda/share/jupyter/nbextensions', '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions', '/usr/share/jupyter/nbextensions']
[D 15:42:17.861 NotebookApp] searching for local mathjax in [u'/Users/kataev/.ipython/profile_default/static', '/Users/kataev/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/static']
[I 15:42:17.861 NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
[I 15:42:17.907 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/kataev/Dropbox
[I 15:42:17.907 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 15:42:17.907 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 15:42:17.907 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[D 15:42:18.372 NotebookApp] Using contents: services/contents
[D 15:42:18.406 NotebookApp] 200 GET /tree (::1) 35.45ms
[D 15:42:18.424 NotebookApp] 304 GET /static/custom/custom.css?v=900035aa0c126bb85df55c5b3e51b6f1 (::1) 9.73ms
..........
[D 15:42:50.262 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/config/common?_=1438778570039 (::1) 0.51ms
[D 15:42:50.335 NotebookApp] 304 GET /api/kernelspecs (::1) 1.01ms
[D 15:42:50.372 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents/ipython/cr_ltv_by_platforms.ipynb?type=notebook&_=1438778570040 (::1) 18.21ms
[D 15:42:50.558 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50877
[I 15:42:50.561 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 0db5ef20-9ce9-4116-8009-617ea52037ef
[D 15:42:50.561 NotebookApp] Kernel args: {'cwd': u'/Users/kataev/Dropbox/ipython'}
[D 15:42:50.563 NotebookApp] 201 POST /api/sessions (::1) 22.50ms
[D 15:42:50.565 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents/ipython/cr_ltv_by_platforms.ipynb/checkpoints?_=1438778570041 (::1) 1.70ms
[D 15:42:50.586 NotebookApp] Initializing websocket connection /api/kernels/0db5ef20-9ce9-4116-8009-617ea52037ef/channels
[D 15:42:50.589 NotebookApp] Requesting kernel info from 0db5ef20-9ce9-4116-8009-617ea52037ef
[D 15:42:50.589 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50874
[I 15:42:53.558 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
[D 15:42:53.562 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50877
[I 15:42:56.567 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5)
[D 15:42:56.572 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50877
[I 15:42:59.576 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
[D 15:42:59.581 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50877
[W 15:43:00.592 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 0db5ef20-9ce9-4116-8009-617ea52037ef
[D 15:43:00.592 NotebookApp] Opening websocket /api/kernels/0db5ef20-9ce9-4116-8009-617ea52037ef/channels
[D 15:43:00.593 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50874
[D 15:43:00.593 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50875
[D 15:43:00.593 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50876
[I 15:43:02.584 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 0db5ef20-9ce9-4116-8009-617ea52037ef restarted
[D 15:43:02.591 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50877
Abort trap: 6
```

OsX Yosemite if it matters. Any thoughts?